# .. (dot dot) in URLs

Tags: security, http, url

Consider a web service that is requested by urls like these:

```
samplehost.com/here/comes/a/path
```

The app behind this will take the path (behind `.com`) and look for a file having this path relative to a defined local directory.

So, let's say this public directory is `/home/user/files`, the above URL would serve the file `/home/user/files/here/comes/a/path`

When writing this, bumped into the question what would happen, when someone requests urls like:

```
samplehost.com/../secret
```

Neither curl nor a browser could send this url. Or rather in both cases the webapp received a path where the dot-dot's were removed: `secret`

Where is this mechanism implemented? Is there something else I need to make sure here in order to not get into such a security issue?

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, what you're asking about is called a [path traversal attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app that loads the data has to make sure that only data from the public directory are loaded. Security can be improved additionally by using file system permissions.

You shouldn't rely on client - side checks because they depend on the used client. A hacker can write everything in a HTTP-request.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. I see now, this is much better than checking on a string level. I was not entirely sure if the dot dot removal is done by the clients. It looks like.